# How to change web browser control visiliblity from collapsed to visible on a button click

Tags: asp.net, wpf, wpf-controls

When WPF application runs for first time.. web browser control is set to visiblity="Collapsed" . Want to change it to visible on a button click.

Thanks

Comment: You are in need of [basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx)...

Comment: @H.B. +1 o, I like this page lol it shows off some controls that I am lazy to test lol

Comment: using MVVM to implement. Don't want to keep anything in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

```
myWebBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps. But as said before, you may want to look up the basic concepts:

1. Attach an event handler to the button's click event, probably something like

   `button1.Click += button1_Click_Handler;`
2. Then somewhere declare the method and change the visibility:

   ```cs
   void button1_Click_Handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       wb1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   }
   ```